# numpy boolean indexing of a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

Please go easy on me as I'm still new to numpy and trying to wrap my head around some numpy concepts and I have this question:

**The problem**

I have a numpy array called boxes with `boxes.shape = (2, 200, 4)`.
There are 2 frames, with 200 boxes each, each box has 4 coordinate points.

I have a boolean array called to_keep with `to_keep.shape = (2, 200)`.  For each frame, there is 200d array telling whether to keep that box or not.

I want to filter out `boxes` and keep only those where `to_keep` is true.
My resulting shape should be `filtered_boxes.shape = (2, N, 4)`

The problem is that for the first frame, 25 boxes may be valid.  But for second frame 100 boxes may be valid.

How do I effectively filter out this structure in numpy?

Comment: Add minimal sample data and expected output?

Comment: You have to keep two different arrays because your array cannot be jagged. For example what is `N` in your example? 25 or 100?
The other option is to mask your array.

Comment: can i get 2 different arrays  - a list of arrays - one for each frame with 25 and 100 boxes each?

Comment: If you don't like my answer you'll have to give some feedback.  No one else is rushing to provide something fancier.

Answer (score 0):

An array and boolean mask:

```
In [309]: X = np.arange(2*10*3).reshape(2,10,3)

In [314]: mask = np.random.randint(0,2,(2,10)).astype(bool)
In [315]: mask
Out[315]: 
array([[False, False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,
         True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True, False,  True,  True,
        False]])
```

Iterate on the first dimension:

```
In [316]: [x[i,:] for x,i in zip(X,mask)]
Out[316]: 
[array([[ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11],
        [15, 16, 17],
        [18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26],
        [27, 28, 29]]), 
 array([[33, 34, 35],
        [36, 37, 38],
        [39, 40, 41],
        [45, 46, 47],
        [51, 52, 53],
        [54, 55, 56]])]
```

In general such a mask has a different number of True in each row, so the resulting masked list cannot be reformed into a 3d array.

Comment: i don't know who downvoted this or why.  thanks for the answer.